# OpenWRT настройка сниффера

Tags: openwrt, маршрутизатор, прошивка, tp-link

Есть маршрутизатор TL-WR740N прошили OpenWRT.
Пользователи подключаются через WiFi. Надо осуществить полный контроль траффика по пользователям(IP). Главное увидеть все POST GET запросы.
Как можно это сделать?
Погуглил много раз, пока не нашел работающих вариантов.
пс: У модема не очень много памяти.

Comment: Для таких целей обычно используется прокси, например Squid

Comment: а куда написать айпи прокси сервера на модеме?